# How to install a Linux OS in pendrive and use it?

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, usb-drive, flash-memory, ubuntu-mate

I am currently using UBUNTU in Raspberry Pi4.
I have another PC that has a crashed hard disk. So what I am planning is to get rid of that HDD and use a pen-drive instead. What I am planning is to make a pendrive that is not live and it will be booted every time I open the PC. Is there any software or process that can help me install the OS in the pendrive? I have balena etcher and rpi-imager installed in my UBUNTU. Are they helpful in this situation.

Comment: You'd probably want two thumb drivers *or* an optical disk and a thumb drive. Basically, you'd boot to the optical disk and just pick the thumb drive as your installation disk. All writable disks, including a thumb drive, should appear as destination choices during the installation. I will also mention that replacement drives are inexpensive and Linux (itself) doesn't take up much space. You can get a 128 GB SDD for under well under $50. Disk space is exceptionally cheap these days.

Comment: Have you performed a google search before asking.  The google search for "[pendrive linux](https://www.google.com/search?q=pendrive+linux&oq=pendrive+linux)" puts this top of my search results: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/ .  The technical term you may have missed is `live usb`.  If you google for "how to create Ubuntu live USB" you should come up with some pretty good results.

Comment: Possibly a more relevant link: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: There is a detailed description how to install Ubuntu into a USB drive (like it were installed into an internal drive) at [**this link**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312).